# Show InfoBar in IWpfTextView

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

The example at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.InfoBarDemo demonstrates how an InfoBar can be shown at the top of Visual Studio, above all toolwindows. However, we want to show an Infobar inside a IWpfTextView. Would somebody know how we can get an IVsInfoBarHost that is linked to a given IWpfTextView?

We've already tried to cast the IWpfTextView object itself to IVsInfoBarHost, all of it's properties, but without luck.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

```
    protected bool TryGetInfoBarHost(IWpfTextView view, out IVsInfoBarHost infoBarHost)
    {
        view.Properties.TryGetProperty(typeof(IVsTextView), out IVsTextView textView);

        if (!TryGetWindowFrame(textView, out var frame) ||
            ErrorHandler.Failed(frame.GetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID7.VSFPROPID_InfoBarHost, out var activeViewInfoBar)))
        {
            infoBarHost = null;
            return false;
        }

        infoBarHost = (IVsInfoBarHost)activeViewInfoBar;
        return true;
    }

    protected bool TryGetWindowFrame(IVsTextView textView, out IVsWindowFrame frame)
    {
        if (textView is IVsTextViewEx vsTextViewEx)
        {
            vsTextViewEx.GetWindowFrame(out object ppFrame);

            if (ppFrame is IVsWindowFrame vsWindowFrame)
            {
                frame = vsWindowFrame;
                return true;
            }
        }

        frame = null;
        return false;
    }
```